# Using websocket for python web crawler -- rsv is not implemented, yet

Tags: python, web, websocket, web-crawler

I use websocket to make a long-live connection with the target wss-url successfully. But after receiving one message, the code caught an error named "rsv is not implemented, yet" and closed the connection.

It seems that few people have met this problem, which described as "rsv is not implemented, yet". And the API doc of websocket never mention this issue.

The main piece of my code:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print("!!!find error!!!")
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### why closed ???###")

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url, 
                on_message = on_message, 
                on_error = on_error, 
                on_close = on_close, 
                header = header, 
                cookie = cookie,
            )
ws.run_forever(origin = 'https://matters.news', skip_utf8_validation = True)
```

It will give me only **one** message, and then show that:

```
!!!find error!!!
rsv is not implemented, yet
send: b'\x88\x82\xd9\xe2\xcc\x8c\xda\n'
### why closed ???###
```

Comment: Could you give us the code and the traceback, please. Unless someone has had this very specific problem, it's hard for us to help you. What did the "few people" say about the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. "Few people" make an issue under the github of the websocket team. But there is no answer until now.

Comment: Are you sure this is an actual issue? Because the `rsv` bit should always be `0` for instance and if someone else has decided to send you a RSV packet, most likely, it doesn't do anything or it has special meaning to your application - meaning the library you're using doesn't need to worry about it. Your application should still keep on running, despite this error, or?

Comment: As you can see, the function `on_error` did run. In addition, my sublime showed `[Finished in 4.0s]` indicated that my application has stopped.

Comment: Some one on github said *This is caused probably by kernel tcp buffers being overrun.* Is that right? And how can I solve it?

Comment: If that's the case, you probably have an issue some where that isn't related to the code. I'll warn you, changing some kernel parameters and values are dangerous in a stability point of view. But here's a good list https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/ of things you can try out. See if that has any affect on your issue. Is it a client or server you're trying to implement? I'm guessing it's a client, if so, why are you not using `on_open`? You should also check out inheriting and creating a class with `recv_frame` to handle buffers better.

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error and fixed it by **removing**:

```
'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate'
```

from my **headers**.